# Read aspx page data in Android app

Tags: android, asp.net

My Android app need to read data from an aspx page.

The aspx page expects some values from the user. When the user clicks the "Go" button, it does some calculation and provides three different values.

My app needs to read these values after they are calculated. Please suggest a method to achieve this. I Googled for some answers and couldn't find a conclusive answer.

Comment: Please show the code around the go button.

Comment: The 'Go' button is from a third party website. My app need to fetch the content after clicking the 'Go' button.

Comment: Yes of course we understand that. So show the source so we have an idea what the content would be. Why let us guess?

Comment: The website is: http://www.overnitenet.com/National-Rate-Calculator.aspx

Comment: Sorry but i cannot see the source with my Android device. (android browsers all lacking a show source). So please post a relevant part of the source. This is my third request.

Answer (score 0):

How does the server handle the Go button? You can use a packet sniffer like Wireshark and try to capture the packet send to the server which performs the 'Go' operation. You can then mimic this packet and send similar packets to the server from your application.

Depending on the format of the values returned, you can parse the data returned from the request issued with the packet sent.